# notifysetdatachanged() error how to set?

Tags: android

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Appointments.this, contactListpnt,R.layout.appointmentlist, abc,new int[]{R.id.tpatientapt, R.id.tphnapt, R.id.tdateapt, R.id.ttymapt, R.id.ttypep, R.id.tstatusp, R.id.tflwupsp, R.id.tnotesp});

            listaptmnt.setAdapter(adapter);
```

notifysetdatachanged() error how to set?

Comment: can you post error log?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below code for fixing error...

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Process: com.example.guru.pro, PID: 14411
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131558572, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.SimpleAdapter)]
                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1573)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2222)
                                                                          at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15900)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Appointments.this, contactListpnt,R.layout.appointmentlist, abc,new int[]{R.id.tpatientapt, R.id.tphnapt, R.id.tdateapt, R.id.ttymapt, R.id.ttypep, R.id.tstatusp, R.id.tflwupsp, R.id.tnotesp});

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listaptmnt.setAdapter(adapter);
}


Process: com.example.guru.pro, PID: 17971
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131558572, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.SimpleAdapter)]
```

Answer (score 0):

put ur notifySetDataChanged in uithread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter. notifysetdatachanged();
                }
            });
```